# What is the meaning of numbers in inline assemble

Tags: linux-kernel, inline-assembly

Do anyone know what the following code does? 
I'm not sure what the 1, 2, 3 is refered and how they are used here. :-(

```
 95         asm volatile("2: wrmsr ; xor %[err],%[err]\n"
 96                      "1:\n\t"
 97                      ".section .fixup,\"ax\"\n\t"
 98                      "3:  mov %[fault],%[err] ; jmp 1b\n\t"
 99                      ".previous\n\t"
100                      _ASM_EXTABLE(2b, 3b)
101                      : [err] "=a" (err)
102                      : "c" (msr), "" (low), "d" (high),
103                        [fault] "i" (-EIO)
104                      : "memory");
105         return err;​
```

The code is from Linux: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h#L91

I really appreciate it ​if anyone could give me some key word to google it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [local labels](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#index-local-labels-217) (numbers followed by a colon).

When they are later referenced, the `b` (as in `jmp 1b`) means to refer to the nearest local label of that number going **backwards**. An `f` would look for a matching local label later (**forwards**) in the code.

That code declares an exception table, when an exception occurs executing the `wrmsr` instruction, the fault handler (usually in `arch/<your_CPU_arch>/mm/fault.c`) searches the exception table for the corresponding entry, and jumps there.

As you can see, the entry for that exception moves `EIO` into `err`, and jumps back to the instruction following the `xor` (which would clear `err` in case there was no error).